# Android pattern reuse code java desktop

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm making a simple program in java desktop using sqlite to store local data,
I wonder if there is a designer pattern that I can reuse the code java desktop to develop the same application for android
in my project I am using mvc pattern

this is the most appropriate for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most appropriate design pattern for your problem will, as always, depend on the details of your  your problem.  If your application deals primarily with CRUD operations, MVC is a great approach.

Design patterns won't change drastically between desktop and Android. How you implement the pattern may, but the pattern itself will still work.

Comment: Hello William Morrison Thank you.
I have an intermediate knowledge in java for android, cycle activitys, Views, BaseAdapter, Handlers, AsyncTask, persistence with sqlite. my application is not very big, is a system for control of personal finances, basically some CRUD

Comment: Then yes, MVC is going to work great for you. You sound like you have all the skills needed to pull it off. Good luck!